# set field value based on other fields values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a validation rule in Access 2010 to set the value of a true/false field to True...

More details, I have a table with several yes/no fields and one true/false field and I want the true/false field to change to true only if all the yes/no fields are yes.

I'm trying to make it that it is set automatically after updating the fields and without the user changing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Validation Rule can not alter a field's value.  It can only indicate whether or not that value should be considered valid.

If you want a field which automatically updates itself to indicate whether other fields are all True, consider a calculated field or a data macro.  Since you're using Access 2010, both those options are supported.

However, a simpler approach would be to decide you don't need that summary field to exist in your table design.  You could use a query to derive it whenever you need to see it.

For example, with two Yes/No fields *Fld1* and *Fld2*, a simple field expression will tell you whether both are True ...

```sql
SELECT Fld1, Fld2, (Fld1=True AND Fld2=True) AS all_are_true
```

That would present True as -1 and False as 0.  If you want the query to show those values as True or False, you can use a `Format` expression ...

```sql
SELECT Fld1, Fld2, Format((Fld1=True AND Fld2=True), 'True/False') AS all_are_true
```

That computation is a trivial workload for the db engine.  And computing the field expression each time you run the query ensures *all_are_true* reflects the latest changes to the other fields.